# Android: references to findViewById

Tags: java, android, memory, reference, findviewbyid

I have been doing this for all my activities when I reference an element from my UI, I create a class variable. This can sometimes lead to 10 - 20 class variables just for UI elements:

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        LinearLayout addComment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);
            addComment = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addcomment);
            addComment.setOnClickListener( // add an onclick listener here //);
        }
    }
```

Now, I have observed by looking at other people's code that sometimes they would do this instead:

```
   public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // LinearLayout addComment; no more reference to class variable

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);
        //they just findViewById and add on the onclick listener
        findViewById(R.id.addcomment).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Is the second method more memory efficient? There is no longer a class variable strong reference and therefore garbage collection can happen more easily. But I'm just wondering what the risk is of using the second method. If garbage collection happens when using the app, does the `addComment linearLayout` lose its click functionality?

I'm just trying ways to optimise my app's memory use.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the second method more memory efficient?

Not particularly. The `LinearLayout addComment` reference costs ~8 bytes.

> There is no longer a class variable strong reference and therefore garbage collection can happen more easily

Not in this case, since other things are holding onto the `LinearLayout`. After all, `findViewById()` is getting the `LinearLayout` from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks - I had this perception that the second method was more memory efficient and was actually about to change all my references to look like the second method instead.

Comment: @Simon: Well, only bother holding onto a widget in a field if you plan on using the field later on. If this is the one-and-only spot where the field is being used, either switch to the second approach or use a local variable. What is decidedly *worse* is to keep calling `findViewById()` over and over, retrieving the same widget. That has CPU and heap fragmentation costs.